# How to convert String to Bar entry for MPCharts in android

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

In my android application, I am new to graphs and using **MPchart library** to draw the graphs. I'm displaying the graph using string array on both - X axis and Y axis.

For x axis I created it successfully but for Y axis I need to convert my `ArrayList<String>` to `BarData` array list. I don't know how to do convert it. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

**For X axis:**

```
private ArrayList<String> getXAxis() {
            ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
            xAxis = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(bar_graph_names)); //converting string to arraylist
            return xAxis;
        }
```

**For Y axis plotting values:**

```
private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getData() {
        ArrayList<String> yAxis_conv = new ArrayList<>();
        yAxis_conv = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(bar_graph_values));

        ArrayList<BarDataSet> yAxis_Datasets=null;
        ArrayList<BarEntry> yAxis = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < bar_graph_values.length; i++)
        {
            BarEntry [] barentry = new BarEntry[bar_graph_values.length];
            barentry[i] = new BarEntry(Float.valueOf(yAxis_conv.get(i)),i);
        }           

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(yAxis_conv , "");//Error occurring line
        barDataSet1.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        yAxis_Datasets = new ArrayList<>();
        yAxis_Datasets.add(barDataSet1);
        return yAxis_Datasets;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BarData` object (which you give to the chart `View`) consist of one `List` representing x-values and one or more `BarDataSet` objects representing y-values data. `BarDataSet` object has `String` name and `List` of y-values.

Your structure of this objects is simply wrong. (for starters `yAxis_conv` is `List<String>`, where `BarDataSet` requires `List<BarEntry>`). There's more mistakes, but i'm not gonna point them out, just have some working code below:

```
private void setData() {
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    xVals = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(bar_graph_names));
    for(int i=0; i < bar_graph_values.length; i++) {
        BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(Float.valueOf(bar_graph_values[i]), i);
        yVals.add(entry);
    }
    BarDataSet newSet = new BarDataSet(yVals, "DataSet");
    BarData data = new BarData(xVals, newSet);
    mChart.setData(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy..can u tell me where i did the mistakes @InTwoMinds

Comment: You're initializing `barentry` array inside every step of for loop, then you add one element to this array and then don't use it  anymore for anything. If you need more examples refer to project samples: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample
Consider marking my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks dude it really helps and thanks for pointing my mistakes..;)